# How to get all documents based on id?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have value from client side.Lets assume `createdBy` by is `ts768n` now i want to find all documents that are created by this user and send it to client , I do not see any error on server side but i have 500 on client side. How can i get all documents that are `createdBy` `ts768n` and send it to client ? `findByIdAsync` does not seems to be working.

templateModel.js

```
var User = require('../user/user.model.js');

var TemplateSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  id: String,
  appliesTo: [],
  properties: [],
  createdBy: { type: String, ref: 'User' }
});

export default mongoose.model('Template', TemplateSchema);
```

templateCtrl.js

```
export function show(req, res) {
  eTemplate.findByIdAsync(req.params.createdBy)
    .then(responseWithResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}


function responseWithResult(res, statusCode) {
  statusCode = statusCode || 200;
  return function(entity) {
    if (entity) {
      res.status(statusCode).json(entity);
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: did you try `eTemplate.findAsync({ createdBy: req.params.createdBy})`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with a simple find asynchronous?

```
eTemplate.findAsync({createdBy: req.params.createdBy})
        .then(responseWithResult(res))
        .catch(handleError(res));
```

Comment: Glad to hear :)